# Converting .h5 to .tflite reducing my model precision in terms of prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras, precision

Hi everyone I tried converting my model from .h5(keras) to .tflite by using the below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model06.h5")
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(keras_model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('model06.tflite', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(tflite_model)
```

But after converting into .tflite my predictions has some loss in precision is there any better way to convert model without any loss in precision of model

Answer (score 0):

This is normal to have a loss in precision; in fact this is the expected phenomenon to happen, it is a trade-off between speed and accuracy.

The only thing you could do is to use `float16` instead of `int8` while converting in order to mitigate the precision loss.